# How do i archive multiple files into a single zip file in git bash?

Tags: git, bash

So, using GitBash I was able to find out that I could archive a single file into a zip file using the following command:

```
git archive -o download_files.zip HEAD exampleproc.sql
```

Is there any way I can archive MULTIPLE files into this single zip file?

Comment: I am getting a 'Not a Valid Object Name' error. Do you know why this might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), you specify all the files that you want to include. So in your case, it could look like this:

```
git archive -o download_files.zip HEAD file1.sql file2.sql
```

Note: This has nothing to do with GitHub by the way, but rather Git itself.

Comment: Thanks, When I use the command, do I need to make sure all of those files are in the same directory and/or folder?

Comment: You can add any files or folders relative to your current working directory. Also, do not forget to accept the answer as correct.